# The controller of custom directive doesn't work with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to build 2 custom directive, my-tile and my-tile-item.

"my-tile" is the main directive which accepts an argument of a data array.

"my-tile-item" represent an individual tile inside the "my-tile".

But btnOkClick() method of my-tile-item controller does not work.

Code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdWgVG

HTML:

```
<div my-tile tiles="mainCtrl.tiles"></div>
```

my-tile template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTile.html">
    <div my-tile-item ng-repeat="tileItem in myTileCtrl.tiles" class="my-tile">
        <div>{{tileItem.id}}</div>
        <button ng-click="myTileItemCtrl.btnOKClick()">OK</button>
    </div>

</script>
```

my-title directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myTile',
        [
            myTile
        ]);


    function myTile() {
       return {
           restrict: 'AE',
           scope: {
             tiles: '='
           },

           controller: ['$scope', MyTileController],
           controllerAs: 'myTileCtrl',


           templateUrl: 'myTile.html',

           link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
               console.log('abc');
           }
       };


       function MyTileController($scope) {
           var ctrl = this;
           ctrl.tiles = $scope.tiles;
       }

    }
```

my-tile-item directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myTileItem',
        [
            myTileItem
        ]);


    function myTileItem() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {

            },

            controller : ['$scope', MyTileItemController],
            controllerAs : 'myTileItemCtrl',

            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

            }
        };


        function MyTileItemController($scope) {
            var ctrl = this;

            ctrl.btnOKClick = function () {
                alert('OK Clicked'); // ********* does NOT work *************
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: haven't found the solution but part of the problem is this: your `ng-click` is never taken in account. I tried `ng-click="console.log('test'); myTileItemCtrl.btnOKClick()"` and i have nothing, while `onclick="console.log('test'); myTileItemCtrl.btnOKClick()"` shows the log 'test' at least (but the function seems never called, and no error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as expected. Since `my-tile-item` directive has its own isolated scope with its own controller doesn't mean that, directive scope will be applied over that element. The scope of directive gets compiled with element, when directive has its own `template` or `transcluded content`. So over here in `my-title-item` directive you don't have its `template`, that's why directive doesn't applied directive scope on element on which it has been hosted.

To solve your problem you can make your `myTileItemCtrl` scope available on element after generating inner template from `my-title-item` directive. Then you could consider passing `item` as scope binding to `my-title-item` from `my-tile` directive.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTile.html">
    <div ng-repeat="tileItem in myTileCtrl.tiles" class="my-tile">
       <my-tile-item item="tileItem"></my-tile-item>
    </div>
</script>
```

**my-item Directive**

```
function myTileItem() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
          item: '<'
        },
        template: `
          <div>{{item.id}}</div>
          <button ng-click="myTileItemCtrl.btnOKClick()">OK</button>
        `,
        //...
    }
}
```

[**Forked Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oedvwG?editors=1010)

By having above template structure you also achieved [**`Smart and Dumb Component Pattern`**](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) where parent is almost responsible for main responsibility, where as child only accepts binding and present it on view.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').directive('myTileItem',
        [
            myTileItem
        ]);


    function myTileItem() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
              scope.btnOKClick = function () {
                alert('OK Clicked');
            }
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

move the btnOnClick to link function of tileItem directive and also remove the scope:{} it will start working. And change `<button ng-click="mytileItemCtrl.btnOKClick()">OK</button>` to `<button ng-click="btnOKClick()">OK</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.

I've changed your codepen and now it's working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLxNvE

First wrong fix could be to remove the isolated scope in your item directive, simply removing the block `scope` of your item directive. 
In this way your item directive will access the scope of the parent and can override that scope adding new properties (as your function).

But this is the wrong solution.

**Following the best approach without removing isolated scope in the item directive**

You are not defining a template for your item directive. You should add a template for what you're trying to achieve because if you isolate the scope then your controller will be accessible only in the template of that directive, without seeing the parent's scope. Not having a corresponding template, that function cannot be called there.

Then the best thing to do in these cases is that you should provide a scope parameter inside the item directive definition, which is actually the item (I did it with two way data binding but I have no idea what you are trying to do, so change the binding according to your requirements).

In this way everything will work fine.